# nth term of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

What would be the $7^{th}$ term of the series

$$8/5 +16/65+24/325+...... $$

Here the numerators are multiples of 8 but the denominators are somewhat not following some simple function.

Here it is $5,13(5),13(5)^2,.. 
.. $.

Going according to this let us consider our first term to be $16/13(5)$ then we need to find the sixth term (seventh term of the actual series)  thus

$$T_6=56/13(5^6)$$

But the correct answer is $     56/9605 $

How do I compute the actual solution?

Comment: Can you factor 9605?

Comment: Well 9605=5x17x113 if that is any help.  Not sure that it does.

Comment: How would this help @GerryMyerson

Comment: https://oeis.org/A211412 the denominator is 4n^4 +1.  I don't have the slightest idea how you were expected to *guess* that.

Comment: @flea, well done! Maybe the way to guess that would be to have the lucky idea of factoring denominator minus 1. Or, here's another way; denominators are $1\times5,5\times13,13\times25,\dots$, and the difference between the two factors is $4,8,12,\dots$.

Comment: @fleablood Wow. Not the slightest idea, either, unless there was more in the original question than posted.

Comment: I had to google.  And it wasn't the top hit.  Apparently 5 is the first number that is the sum of two squares, 65 is the first that is the sum of two squares in two distinct ways, and 325 is the first sum of two squares in three distinct ways.

Comment: oeis.org is pretty amazing.

Comment: @flea, sum of two *positive* squares in two distinct ways. $25=4^2+3^2=5^2+0^2$.

Comment: two positive square *integers*, if you are going to be picky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$T_n = \frac {8n}{4n^4+1} $

Not sure how you were supposed to guess that with only three terms.  We're you given any more info as to what format the terms should be.

There was no reason to assume the denominators were $D_n=13*5^{n-1} $ as the first denominator is $5$ and not $13$.